# Using VBA to paste range into Outlook does not paste anything

Tags: vba, excel, email, outlook

I'm trying to automate a report so that it copies a range, pastes it in the body of an email, and sends it.

I'm using the exact code [Ron De Bruin](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm) gave out, just with my own range entered and a filter statement.

Everything works fine, except when I receive/display the email, it's just a blank email to me. There's no pasted range in it. What I find weird is that this works fine until I filter the range. When I use any kind of filter on it, it breaks and I'm not sure why.

For reference, here is the exact code I'm working with: `

```
Sub Mail_Selection_Range_Outlook_Body()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="<>"
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Brittany"

    Set rng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    'Only the visible cells in the selection
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A:F").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    rng.Copy
    ActiveSheet.Range("U1").Paste

        On Error GoTo 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
               vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "email@email.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Test for Updates"
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
        .Display   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub



Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

`

Comment: Why don't you copy paste the filtered data to a Temporary Storage sheet (Hidden Sheet) and use that sheets range reference in your code?

Comment: @Sixthsense, isn't that pretty much what the RangetoHTML function does?

Comment: Filtered range will have non contiguous range so, that may cause issue in pushing the data to outlook. So it is better to copy paste the data to a helper sheet and using the contiguous range in RangeToHTML may be considered as an option.

Comment: You could take a picture of the range you are interesting to paste into your email body.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use this for emails, but for creating a task. I, however, modified it a bit, tested it, and it works, even when filtered.

```
Dim olApp As Object
Dim olRem As Object
Dim myRange As Range

Dim olInsp As Object
Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim oRng As Object

Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olRem = olApp.CreateItem(0)

Set myRange = Selection

myRange.Copy

Set olInsp = olRem.GetInspector
Set wdDoc = olInsp.WordEditor
Set oRng = wdDoc.Range


With olRem
.Subject = "Call " & contact & " - " & company & " - " & city & ", " & state
oRng.InsertAfter (oRng.PasteAndFormat(wdFormatOriginalFormatting))
oRng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
oRng.InsertBreak (wdLineBreak)
oRng.InsertAfter (Comment)
oRng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
oRng.InsertBreak (wdLineBreak)
oRng.InsertAfter (oRng.PasteAndFormat(wdFormatOriginalFormatting))
.display
End With

Set olApp = Nothing
Set olRem = Nothing
Set olInsp = Nothing
Set wdDoc = Nothing
Set oRng = Nothing
Set myRange = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

This will paste paste your set range of Col A to Col F, or you can modify slightly to paste a selected range, but I don't understand how the filter works so I commented out.  I see the filter added to the column headers in the worksheet, but the entire range is still pasted.

**Code:**

```
Sub pasteRangeBody()
  Dim IsCreated As Boolean
  Dim OutlApp As Object
  Dim RngCopied As Range

    ' ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    ' ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>"
    ' ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Brittany"

  With ActiveSheet
  ' Set RngCopied = Selection
    Set RngCopied = ActiveSheet.Range("A:F").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
  End With

  On Error Resume Next
  Set OutlApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
  If Err Then
    Set OutlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    IsCreated = True
  End If
  On Error GoTo 0


  With OutlApp.CreateItem(0)
    .Display         ' Display email first for signature to be added
    .Subject = ""
    .To = ""
    .CC = ""
    .HTMLbody = RangetoHTML(RngCopied) & _
        "Thank you," & _
        .HTMLbody      ' Add default signature
    On Error Resume Next

    Application.Visible = True
    If Err Then
      MsgBox "Unsuccessful", vbExclamation
    Else
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
  End With

  If IsCreated Then OutlApp.Quit
  Set OutlApp = Nothing
End Sub


Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2010
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```